# Find number of partitions computed per machine in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Currently, I am investigating the possibility of workload imbalance in my Apache Spark clusters.
Is it possible to see the number of partitions assigned per machine in the Apache Spark UI or history server?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the Spark UI, but here is how you can achieve it programmatically -

```
def partitionsComputed(): Unit ={
    import java.net.InetAddress
    import org.apache.spark.TaskContext

    sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 3).mapPartitions(_ => {
      val ctx = TaskContext.get
      val partId = ctx.partitionId
      val hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostName
      Iterator.apply[(String,Int)]((hostName,partId))
    })
      .groupByKey()
      .foreach(m => println("Hostname-"+m._1+" , Number of Partitions Computed-"+m._2.size))
  }
```

The result will be printed in the consolidated log of spark application. You can collect the result and print on the drive node as well.